# Passing an object into $(window).bind()

Tags: jquery, function, object, scope

I have a general (custom) jQuery plugin. $.fn.something(). This gets called on some objects in my DOM. Lets say

```
$('div.section').something()
```

Inside the function, I have something like this...

```
$.fn.something = function(options) {

    //here **this** refers to $('div.section') which is what I want

    $(window).bind('scroll', function(){
        //how do I get the 'this' from above into here.
    });

});
```

I can't for the life of me get the reference to "this" from inside the plugin INSIDE the .bind() function. I have a workaround where I store "this" into the options array and pass it that way, but I can't help thinking that there is a more straightforward way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the value of `this` in a variable and then use that instead...

```
$.fn.something = function(options) {

    var that = this;

    $(window).bind('scroll', function(){
        // use that!
    });

});
```

This may seem like a hack, but it is *very* common place.

If you're able to use the methods introduced in ES5, without worrying about [backwards compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Browser_compatibility), you could also use the [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function;

```
$(window).bind('scroll', (function(){
    // use this
}.bind(this)));
```

Comment: Great, this was more than enough to give me peace of mind. Much thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

use a variable.

```
$.fn.something = function(options) {

    var self = this;

    $(window).bind('scroll', function(){
        //use self.options
    });

});
```

This is a trick I learned from knockoutjs

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.something = function(options) {

    var self=this;

    $(window).bind('scroll', function(){
        //you can now use self
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $.proxy:

$.fn.something = function(options) {

```
$(window).bind('scroll', $.proxy(function(){
    //you can now use this
}, this));
```

});